# Data fetch of processes on windows

Tags: windows

I want to get information like PID, Memory utilization, cpu utilization corresponding resource name etc. from Sysinternals to an excel sheet . Is it possible to directly collect all these information from Sysinternals (not from Task manager) and save that to a excel sheet.

EDIT1

```
wmic process get /format:csv > my.csv
```

It gives unwanted data also in non readable structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wmic process get /format:csv > my.csv
```

and you can open the csv with excel..hope that helps.Not the full information ,but is the best that can be achieved with simple batch.

**Edit:**

```
wmic process where Name='hsvDatasource.exe' get /Format:Textvaluelist
```

You can see formats [here](http://ss64.com/nt/wmicstylesheets.html) and choose the one you like.
to filter the data you need to list the wanted columns:

```
wmic process where Caption='hsvDatasource.exe' get ProcessId,VirtualSize /Format:Textvaluelist
```

(Virtual size should be the memory)

the whole info about the process properties , [you can find here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**Edit 2** 
To get CPU consumption you can use a powershell command (powershell is installed by default on windows 7 and may be vista) .Not possible in simple batch :

```
c:\>powershell get-process ^| where-object {$_.Id -eq 1052}
```

For total cpu usage check typeperf and logman commands

Comment: Thanx for your response !! but It gives unwanted data also in non readable structure,i just wanted to get following information only for all hsvDatasource.exe processes running in Sysinternals PROCESS EXPLORER at an interval of 1 hr updated in a single excel sheet on desktop.


Process name Process ID  Virtual Memory Utilization  CPU Utilization

Comment: Its working superbly..thanx a lot..!!..but a process class for % CPU Utilization is given nowhere in process properties.

Comment: Can we get the application name running under hsvDatasource.exe process ?

Comment: Do you mean a subprocess ? Or the hsvDatasource.exe could be start with different name?

Comment: actually i am not able to attach the image which could present the clear picture..don;t know why i am not able to attach the image here..:(..how i can attach a screenshot of my issue here..?

Comment: another option is : If I can check whether HsvDataSource.exe processes are running in Sysinternals PROCESS EXPLORER or not ? and if running, then save the full page information (which can be done in PROCESS EXPLORER by selecting File->Save as OR directly by Ctrl+A)as a text file by selecting each and every HsvDataSource.exe processes seperately because in that text file Application name is occurring.

Comment: check handle.exe -> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx - with this you must be able to list all handles per PID and pick-up the desired log file.

Comment: Waaw..handle.exe actually resolved my problem..many thanks Npocmaka for your great assistance..!! :)